# highstock, why my xAxis not show like the tooltip? the tooltip is correct to my local time

Tags: c#, asp.net, typescript, highcharts

my xAxis not show like the tooltip
I tried put in xAxis: pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000 // one day
I have 300-350 point for one day (difference from 2 points is 5- 10 min)

[image]

```
 series: [{

                name: 'Price',
                type: 'area',
                data: (() => {

                    var data = [];
                    for (let i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++) {

                        let timeHistory = (new Date(this.data[i].d).toLocaleString()).valueOf();
                        this.firstPoint = (new Date(this.data[0].d).toLocaleString()).valueOf();
                        data[i] = [timeHistory, this.data[i].p];
                    }
                    this.$scope.graphSeries = data;
                    return data;
                })(),

            }]
```

Thank in advance

Comment: Are you using formatters in your xAxis or tooltip? Your data may be shifted according to UTC time and Local time difference. You may try setting useUTC to false: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/global.useUTC

Comment: Tried that but still not working

Comment: What, specifically, is it that you want the x axis to display, and what is the problem with what it is currently displaying?

Comment: In tooltip it show the local time :
12:20:00 PM
in the xAxis it shows : 02:46 (under the point).
My tooltip is correct and the xAxis is not, I want that my xAxis will be the same like tooltip